# Redux connect function error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

If I change this line

> let Auth = connect(null,null)(AuthScreen)

with this

> let Auth = AuthScreen

everything works. However, I need to use redux and I get this error

> Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a
>   function component.
>
> This error is located at:
>       in ConnectFunction (created by SceneView)
>       in SceneView (created by SwitchView)
>       in SwitchView (created by Navigator)
>       in Navigator (at createAppContainer.js:387)
>       in NavigationContainer (at App.js:29)
>       in Provider (at App.js:28)
>       in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
>
> This error is located at:
>       in NavigationContainer (at App.js:29)
>       in Provider (at App.js:28)
>       in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)

```
let Auth = connect(null,null)(AuthScreen);

const RootStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  { Auth:  Auth},
  {initialRouteName: 'Auth'}
);

let AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppContainer />
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "untitled16",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.58.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.8.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

AuthScreen.js

```
class AuthScreen extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Text>This is a text</Text>
        ) }}

export default AuthScreen
```

Comment: Please show `AuthScreen`

Comment: I changed AuthScreen as you can see but I still get the same error. @Vencovsky